# Windows 7 ejects external drive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

Windows 7 seems to randomly eject an external drive. I've deactivated the usb sleep mode but it still happens. Not sure if this information is useful but this only seems to happen while I'm running a game which is installed on the external drive. I'm wondering if this could be related to a higher power needed while gaming. My iMac has usb 3 though, so it couldn't be a problem, right? Any idea what else could cause this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the USB loose at all? I have USB ports that are loose and the drive will move around. If you plug the USB in and it finds it, then wiggle it a tiny bit and see if it disconnects.

Comment: I'll try that - but could this really be the problem? the drive just lies on a table and isn't moved at all.

Comment: I'm not saying it's likely, but it's possible. Even if I don't move my USB at all, it still goes on and off in Windows sometimes.

Comment: Sorry it took me that long to check but the external drive doesn't seem to have any loose contact.